# operation AND in .str.contains methode

Tags: python, pandas

i have toy dataframe

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["apple is green",
                       "banana is yellow",
                       "strawberry is red"],
                     'col2': ["dog is kind",
                       "cat is smart",
                       "lion is brave"]})
```

with output:

```
                 col1           col2
0      apple is green     dog is kind
1    banana is yellow    cat is smart
2   strawberry is red   lion is brave
```

i have two targets to search, where first is

`apple` or `lion`
and second one is `brave`:

`target = 'apple|lion'
target2 = 'brave'`

i can search with first target easily:

```
toy_df[toy_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(targets)).any(axis=1)]
```

outpus is:

```
                 col1            col2
0      apple is green     dog is kind
2   strawberry is red   lion is brave
```

but how i shoud search with TWO targets (`target1 and target2`) ? to get this output:

```
                 col1            col2
2   strawberry is red   lion is brave
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical **AND** (`&`) to combine both boolean conditions:

#### Example

```
mask1 = toy_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(targets)).any(axis=1)
mask2 = toy_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(target2)).any(axis=1)

toy_df[mask1 & mask2]
```

[out]

```
                col1           col2
2  strawberry is red  lion is brave
```

---

#### Update - full code

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["apple is green",
                       "banana is yellow",
                       "strawberry is red"],
                     'col2': ["dog is kind",
                       "cat is smart",
                       "lion is brave"]})

targets = 'apple|lion'
target2 = 'brave'

mask1 = toy_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(targets)).any(axis=1)
mask2 = toy_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(target2)).any(axis=1)

toy_df[mask1 & mask2]
```

Comment: i have this error with your code:
`unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: what is `print(mask1.dtype)` and ``print(mask2.dtype)`` please?

Comment: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: ok so that's not right, `mask1` and `mask2` should be `boolean` dtype `Series` not `DataFrame` - have you definately used `.any(axis=1`) and have you got it in the right place? double check your parenthesis if any

Comment: i need `.any(axis=1)` in this code. and parenthesis are right. i can open `mask1` and `mask2` separately

Comment: I added a full code snippet, can you copy and paste exactly and check if it's working? I suspect you've got a small typo somewhere when you're adapting it to your real dataset